# Eitz Chaim; Shaar Rachel v’Leah / Yahel Ohr / Derech Mitzvotecha

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, sexuality, adam, leil-shabbat, eve-chava

Can anyone point me to an English translation of Eitz Chaim - Specifically Shaar Rachel v’Leah, chapter 2 - please?

I've come across a reference to it in relation to Adam and Eve's relationship and the idealisation of sexual relations occurring on Friday night here:
https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/555601/jewish/Lilith-Adam-Eve-and-the-real-original-sin.htm

Likewise they reference Yahel Ohr (Tzemach Tzedek al haTehillim) 127:8 and Derech Mitzvotecha, Mitzvat Pru Urvu (page 498).

I want to compare Ari's and the other's theories to Koryah's (see my query here: [Who is Rabbi Koryah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/134532/who-is-rabbi-koryah)), but sefaria only partially translates Eitz Chaim, and not this portion.
I can't find anything  clear regarding the other referenced works.

Can someone please either point me to a translation of the works, or if not that, then would anyone be willing to kindly translate/transcribe?

Comment: Most people who translate advanced Kabbalistic works into English or another language are not working in the Orthodox framework. There is an understanding that these are not books that one can just pick up and read without a thorough background in more basic Judaism. Even those who can read these types of works in the original Hebrew, need a teacher well-versed in sod HaTorah to learn Eitz Chaim with.

Comment: @IsraelReader I appreciate that, but I'm not looking to learn Kabbalah in-depth at present - Just to see if Ari is referencing Koryah or if he cites another source. The practise of sex on Friday nights occurs enough in non-kabbalist Orthodox workings that I'm surprised to have found so little background for it, so I'm looking for anything I can find.

Comment: ANH there are two main sources for this practice in our Sifrei Kodesh, there is a Gemarra about how this was the practice of Torah Scholars in Jerusalem, and there is a Zohar about the spiritual ramifications of it. If you had to guess, which would you think the Ari was more likely referencing?

Comment: @יהושעק I understand that Ari was likely making a reference to the spiritual aspect, but given that there is uncertainty about who the 'Koryah' making the comment about Adam is (see the linked question), we are left uncertain about where Koryah is getting his own angle on it from. It being the practise in Jerusalem has several further angles of its own. That's why I want to compare the way Ari puts it in Eitz Chaim.